# Efficient ways to retrieve a large table to pandas from oracle sql

Tags: sql, pandas, dataframe

I have a table in oracle sql with 2 billion rows and I was to load that data into pandas dataframe. I have enough ram space(~64GB) and using intel optane as a swap space memory issue. The problem I am facing is it is taking forever to load the data.

Currently, I'm using the following query.

```
query = """select /*+parallel(35)*/ * from twistdw"""
df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
```

That script takes forever to run.

I also tried

```
chunk_size = 5000000
offset = 0
dfs=[]
while True:
    query = """select /*+parallel(35)*/ * from twistdw;""" 
    dfs.append(psql.read_sql(query, conn_twist, chunksize=chunk_size))
    offset += chunk_size
    if len(dfs[-1]) < chunk_size:
        break
full_df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

The above query throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-13-c133ce6f47b0>", line 14, in <module>
    if len(dfs[-1]) < chunk_size:

TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
```

Can I get some help with it?

Answer (score 0):

If `chunksize` is specified, [`read_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html#pandas.read_sql) returns an iterator:

```
chunk_size = 5000000
query = """select /*+parallel(35)*/ * from twistdw;""" 

reader = pd.read_sql(query, conn_twist, chunksize=chunk_size)
full_df = pd.concat(reader, ignore_index=True)
```

See also [docs on reading data chunk by chunk](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk).

Comment: @akash bachu: Did this answer your question and solve your issue? If so then please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If not please comment. This helps keep this site useful and enables others with similar questions quickly find an answer.

Comment: Hey @stef, in this case, all the small frames will be loaded into `full_df` right, now this will be the larger one, While concat, will it throw memory error?

Comment: @Bhuvanesh it certainly depends on the size of the data and the memory, but as the OP didn't experience a memory error in his first solution (`df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)`) I assume it'll be OK in this case. My answer was more to solve the error in the second solution.